# Enable selection by ColumnHeader, RowHeader and Cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to implement excel like feature in `DataGridView`. So:

1. if they select column header it would select the column
2. if the user selects row header then entire row would be selected
3. Apart from this if they select cell, only that single cell would be selected.

To so so, for the third requirement I made the `SelectionMode` as `CellSelect`. For a column selection I selected all the cells in a column , but when I tried to print `SelectedColumns`, it printed as zero. It seems I have to select the column headers also. I don't know how to select column header programmatically. The required code is below. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this?

```
private void dataGridViewFileData_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridViewFileData.MultiSelect = true;
    dataGridViewFileData.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewFileData.Rows.Count; ++i)
         dataGridViewFileData.Rows[i].Cells[0].Selected = true;
    MessageBox.Show("Selected columns:" + dataGridViewFileData.SelectedColumns.Count.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an option you can set the [`SelectionMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to [`CellSelect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectionmode?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8), then handle the [`CellClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and regarding to the row index and column index of the clicked cell and select the cell, or full row or full column or all cells using code.

Since the selection mode is `CellSelect`, selected columns or selected rows are empty and if for any reason you want to track selected column or selected row, you need to track it manually.

The same for visual feedback about the selection, you need to set back color of the headers or paint them yourself. For example:

```
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
    dataGridView1.RowCount = 3;
    dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
    dataGridView1.CellClick += DataGridView1_CellClick;
    dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
}
DataGridViewColumn selectedColumn = null;
DataGridViewRow selectedRow = null;
List<DataGridViewCell> selectedCells = null;
private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

    if (selectedColumn != null)
        selectedColumn.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor =
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
    if (selectedRow != null)
        selectedRow.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor =
            dataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor;

    selectedColumn = null;
    selectedRow = null;
    selectedCells = null;
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectAll();
        selectedCells = new List<DataGridViewCell>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            selectedCells.AddRange(row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>());
    }
    else if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        selectedRow = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
            cell.Selected = true;
    }
    else if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        selectedColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected = true;
    }
    else
    {
        selectedCells = selectedCells = new List<DataGridViewCell>()
            { dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] };
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected = true;
    }
    if (selectedColumn != null)
        selectedColumn.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    if (selectedRow != null)
        selectedRow.HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code also won't select the columnheader or rowheader . Because the index for those is -1. Your code didn't handle this condition. This is the specific condition which I have to handle.

Comment: Obviously selected columns or selected rows are empty, because the selection mode is `CellSelect`.

Comment: If I select all the cells in a column, then won't it be a column select. Thereby selected columns count must be one.

Comment: You are using a `DataGridView` and a selected column is different from having all cells of a column selected. However you can keep the clicked column index/clicked rows index in a variable.

Comment: The  problem is another function deletes the selected multiple columns based on selectedcolumns.count. And I have to visually show the selected columns.

Comment: It's a different problem. I'd say all of these things are possible for example by using variables to track selected column/row/cells or having code for custom rendering of cloumn/row/header. But a question should focus on a single problem.

Comment: Added another piece of code example to the answer. It contains all the basic information what you need to handle the problem. You may want to change it based on your requirement.

Comment: As you said tracking the selected columns is one way. But if I could achieve it through the available datagridview functions, then I can get the benefits of Ctrl+,Shift+ key strokes.Otherwise I have to handle all these things. But it seems that is the only way possible.

Comment: You cannot rely on existing properties of `DataGridView`, for example take a look at [`SelectedColumns`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs,3a4920fe15314e25) source code and how it works. As you see, it's not overridable. You may want to derive from `DataGridView` and shadow all these properties or encapsulate the logic which I described above.

Comment: Anyhow, you may not like it, but it is the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

As another option you can handle [`OnCellMouseDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.oncellmousedown?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event and depending to the clicked cell, decide to set [`SelectionMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionmode?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8). This way, you can get the visual feedback as well as `SelectedColumns` and `SelectedRows`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
    dataGridView1.RowCount = 3;
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
        c.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
    dataGridView1.CellMouseDown += DataGridView1_CellMouseDown;
}
private void DataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;
        dataGridView1.SelectAll();
    }
    else if (e.ColumnIndex == -1 && e.RowIndex > -1)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
    }
    else if (e.ColumnIndex > -1 && e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.ColumnHeaderSelect;
        dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Selected = true;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I also like this option, maybe prefer it. Give it a try or see the screen capture and let me know your feedback.